# Point Files not always aligning based on Coordinate System

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, nad83

I have two CSV files that have GCP points for a drone survey area. The points are exactly the same location just collected in different coordinate systems. First is NAD83 (CSRS) / UTM 10N and the second is WGS84 / UTM 10N. When looking at the Eastings and Northings of each point, they are basically identical (+/- 2cm). When I import them into QGIS under their respective Coordinate systems, they only line up if the QGIS project is in NAD83 / UTM 10N projection and not the NAD83 (CSRS) or WGS84 UTM 10N.

I understand that different projections have different visualizations but both points have the same Eastings and Northings, how can they be 1+m different in their locations?

Comment: because you started measuring from (a slightly) different position in the different CRS - therefore you should use the correct CRS for each layer and then set the map projection to what you want

Comment: Do you have current Grid Shift (GSB) files for BC? That might account for the 1+ Meter difference.

Comment: I am using QGIS version 3.22.3 so I am using the default grid shift included in that. I haven't pulled a new one in.